# How to encode letters in multipart/form-data to include CR/LF characters?

Tags: web-application, attacks, email, http, injection

Part of HTTP request that should be sent to server with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data;` looks like:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryQ7KGYev31biaJTW8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"

attacker_controlled
```

Then this value is included into header of response to another request:

```
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="attacker_controlled.html"
```

I'd want to make HTTP header injection here. How to encode CR/LF characters in `mulupart/formdata` so they will appear as CR/LF at server side? How to make HTTP header injection here if it's not possible?

**Edit:** I've tried to change this request per @AndrewSmith's advice but [it didn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169434/content-transfer-encoding-in-file-uploading-request):

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryQ7KGYev31biaJTW8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

YXR0YWNrZXJfY29udHJvbGxlZA==
```

In resulting HTML in place of `attacker_controlled` there is `YXR0YWNrZXJfY29udHJvbGxlZA==` (i.e. webserver didn't recognize Content-Transfer-Encoding)

So is there way to encode CR/LF characters?

Comment: Could you simply post your full request and full response you got now and tell what is the expected response?

Comment: @AndrewSmith What info do you need besides of already provided? Full HTTP request and response are too long

Comment: I can't tell if you're trying to figure out how to attack some existing system, or if you're trying to figure out how to defend your system.  The answers will differ according to your goal (attack or defense).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are newlines a problem when there is a boundary defined? The thing with this kind of HTTP packet is that it's binary safe, meaning that the entire 0..255 ASCII range can be used with no problem; including newlines and carriage returns. As long as the specified boundary is not encountered, the server or browser will simply see the characters as part of the data and not as any separator.

Only if an attacker can control the name in the content-disposition header, you would need to strip newlines there. Or if they can guess the boundary to be used, you should make sure the boundary is dynamic (unguessable) or removed from anything the attacker submits.

Answer (score -1):

It's 7bit encoding I believe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526290(v=exchg.10).aspx

Please correct me if I am wrong.

It can be also whatever server supports: 8bit, etc, you just put a header and see for yourself how it works, and see what Content-Transfer-Encoding you specify as well.

Comment: So is it possible to encode CR/LF characters?

Comment: Yes it is, but depends on the encoding format you've got.